# addSubview: positioned: relativeTo: not work sometimes

Tags: macos, nsview

I use `[viewA addSubview:viewB positioned: NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil]` to add viewB on top of other subviews of viewA, and the view hierarchy is correct. But in the UI, viewB is not on top, it is still hidden by a viewC.

I found that if viewC is a view which `wantsLayer` or rendered by OpenGL, this issue will happen. But if viewC is a normal view, viewB will be on the top, not hidden by viewC. It seems something about the view render mechanism.

Apple's doc of `addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:` does not say anything about this, so anybody have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried setting relativeTo to a view instead of nil? The documentation for [NSView addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] states that if relativeTo is nil, the added view is added above or below all of its new siblings.

Comment: yeah, already tried, but no effect. I don't think it's the matter of nil. Thanks.

Comment: Since you aren't using relativeTo parameter, why don't you just use [NSView addSubview:]? That might solve your problem.

Comment: I need to specify the view position in the hierarchy, not just put in the view.

Comment: This may be a bug which has been solved in macOS 10.13